# BLE only partially connected in iPhone?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, csr-adk, ios

I am trying to use BLE to send strings of data from a CSR8675 chip to an iPhone

I am having problems pairing the chip with the iPhone for BLE communication, and need some ideas on how to proceed with troubleshooting

Normally if a bluetooth device is properly connected to an iPhone, in the bluetooth settings window it will be shown as **connected** with a blue **i** inside a circle

However, my device is only shown as **connected** and there is no **i** inside a blue circle

At some level, the CSR8675 chip internally considers itself connected to BLE (I know this because if I enable debug messages for the program I am running on the chip, I can see a timer that periodically checks for bluetooth and IO pin activity show a message that BLE is connected)

However, if I try to send bytes from CSR to iPhone or from iPhone to CSR, it doesn't work due to absence of BLE connection, but both devices consider each other connected

I would like to know what it means when the iPhone shows connected without the i symbol. Are there multiple reasons that can cause this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The discussions about the on-topicness of categories of questions belong on meta. Not in the comments on distinct questions.

Comment: @user17915 do you happen to have some code we could see, to better say what may be the issue? Any error messages?

Comment: @mico actually I don't have access to the BLE related app code on the iPhone, and there's not really any error message being shown either. The phone thinks that it's connected to the BLE device but data transfer just doesn't happen. I was just wondering if the fact that there are two "connected" states in the iPhone, one that shows the blue i symbol in a circle and one that does not in the bluetooth settings, would give some clue as to what was the problem. Either way this particular issue has been resolved by updating the BLE device's source code.

Comment: If you don't have access to the code running on the iphone, or a detailed spec for what that accepts, and you won't post the code for the firmware either, then this has to be closed as unanswerably unclear.  For all we can guess at this point, you're expecting something to happen that these devices aren't even intended to support - BLE in particular is highly specific, there's not such thing as generic data transfer, and "connection" is an optional state not even used in all such systems.